# How to add parameters to a node via a yaml file using a python launch file in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, python, ros-humble

I have tried all the solutions I've seen on forums but none seems to work, I've spent already several days on this and really hope someone can spot my mistake rapidly.

I have the following launch file (reduced to the minimum) *my_launch_file.launch.py*:

```
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    param_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('my_pkg'), 'config/my_params.yaml')

    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package="my_pkg",
            executable="my_node",
            parameters=[LaunchConfiguration(param_file)],
        )
    ])
```

And then I have a parameters file named *my_params.yaml*:

```
my_node:
  ros__parameters:
    some_int: 42
    some_bool: true
```

I built my package, verified that the launch file and node is built correctly, and that the my_params.yaml file is at the correct location. However, when I launch my file, I get:

```
user@user-PC:~$ ros2 launch my_pkg my_launch_file.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/user/.ros/log/2023-09-18-15-07-27-467850-user-PC
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): launch configuration '/home/user/ros2_ws/install/my_pkg/share/my_pkg/config/my_params.yaml' does not exist
```

I confirm again that the my_params.yaml file is there, I verified every single character of the path. I also confirm that I sourced the setup.bash from /opt/ros/humble, and the one from ~/ros2_ws/install. Also, the node works and launches correctly if I don't add the parameters file.

Can't find why this is happening, please help!
Thanks in advance!

Setup:
ROS2 Humble,
Ubuntu 22.04

---

EDIT:
I modified the launch file by removing the *LaunchConfiguration*. Now it looks like this:

```
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    param_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('my_pkg'), 'config/my_params.yaml')

    return LaunchDescription([

        Node(
            package="my_pkg",
            executable="my_node",
            parameters=[param_file],
        )
    ])
```

This way, there is no more error in the terminal, but when I do `ros2 param list /my_node`, I get no parameters, so it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So answering my own question,

To make the parameters available to the node, they first need to be declared inside the node.

Hence, the node should be something like:

```
class MyNodeClass(Node):
    """
    A node example
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("my_node")
        self.declare_parameters(
        namespace='',
        parameters=[
            ('some_int', 18),
            ('some_bool', False),
        ])
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Once they get declared here in the node, then the launch file takes the parameters in the yaml file into account. Now when I launch my launch file, and then in another terminal do `ros2 param get /my_node some_int`, I get the answer `Integer value is: 42`, Which shows the yaml file value overwrote the one in the node.